# Error: magento delete cannot complete this operation from non admin area

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento was running successfully till last couple of weeks back. All of a sudden, I am getting error as below

> Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.

When I browse for the issue it suggests different reason but non of them matches with my current situation.

I found that in `app/code/core/mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php` file we have check point as below

```
protected function _protectFromNonAdmin()
    {
        if (Mage::registry('isSecureArea')) {
            return;
        }
        if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.'));
        }
    }
```

The condition `Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()` always returns false despite user logged in as a admin.

Can someone assist me ?

Comment: What's the value of `Mage::app()->getStore()` when logged in ad admin?

Comment: @marius it comes as a long object

Comment: Sorry. I forgot something. The value of `Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()`

Comment: @Marius it comes as '1'

Comment: When on admin side it should come up as 0. But one more question. You are looged on in the backend and you are trying to delete something from the frontend?

Comment: @Marius I logged into admin and tried to delete from customer interface

Comment: what do you mean by "Customer interface"? THe admin panel, or the frontend? If you are trying to delete something using the frontend of the website it won't work, because admin and frontend sessions are not shared. If you are trying to delete something from the admin then there is a problem. Check for an extension that might be affecting the current store you are on. Maybe somehow magento thinks you are in the frontend area when trying to delete something from the admin.

Comment: @Marius You hint (store id should be zero for admin section) helped me a lot. I figured out the issue. Now it is working fine

Comment: Please write what the problem was and how you solved it as an answer to help future readers.